rice's theorem: what if never halts?
Let $P$ be any nontrivial property of the language of a Turing machine. Prove
that the problem of determining whether a given TM’s language has property $P$ is undecidable.
Proof: (from sipser's book)
Assume for the sake of contradiction that $P$ is a decidable language satisfying the properties and let $R_P$ be
the TM that decides $P$.
We show how to decide $A_{TM}$ using $R_P$ by constructing TM $S$.
First let $T_∅$ be a
TM that always rejects, so $L(T_∅)$ = ∅.
You may assume that $<T_∅> \notin P$ without loss of generality, because
you could proceed with $\bar{p}$ instead of $P$ if $<T_∅> \in P$.
Because $P$ is not trivial, there exists a TM $T$ with
$<T> \in P$.
Design $S$ to decide $A_{TM}$ using $R_P$ ’s ability to distinguish between $T_∅$ and $T$.
$S = $“On input $<M, w>:$

Use $M$ and $w$ to construct the following TM $M_w$.
$M_w$ = “On input $x:$

Simulate $M$ on $w$. If it halts and rejects, reject. If it accepts,
proceed to stage $2$.
Simulate $T$ on $x$. If it accepts, accept.”


Use TM $R_P$ to determine whether $<M_w> \in P$. If YES, accept. If NO, reject.”


TM $M_w$ simulates $T$ if $M$ accepts $w$. Hence $L(M_w)$ equals $L(T)$ if $M$ accepts $w$ and $∅$ otherwise.
Question:
"Simulate $M$ on $w$. If it halts and rejects, reject. If it accepts,
proceed to stage $2$."
But what if $M$ does not halt on $w$? Then $M_w$ (and so also $S$) will run forever and we will have no conclusion? Why is this not an issue?

Just because $M_w$ runs forever doesn't mean that $S$ runs forever: $S$ doesn't actually run $M_w$, it just builds (i.e. computes the description of) $M_w$ and then feeds it to $R_P$.
You might object that it's implausible for $R_P$ to be able to tell how $M_w$ behaves without actually running $M_w$, but that's sort of the point of this argument: we're trying to prove that $R_P$ can't exist after all.
